# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Tags: ajax, javascript

I'm trying to use a jquery ticker in my website and this is the code: http://cektkp.com/twittermarquee/twitmarquee.js and I'm getting these errors:

1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined:

```
window.twttr.bounds = window.twttr.bounds || {};
   $.extend(twttr.bounds, {
      Bounds: function (b, d, c, a) {
        this.x = b;
        this.y = d;
        this.width = c;
        this.height = a
      }
});
```

2) Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function (line 37)

```
 function loadTrendDescriptions() {
    $("#trends a").each(function () {
        var A = $(this);
        var C = A.parent().find("em");
        if (C.length) {
            var B = A.text();
            var D = C.text().replace(new RegExp(B.replace(/([^\w])/gi, "\\$1"), "gi"), "<strong>" + B + "</strong>");
            var E = A.attr("title").length ? A.attr("title") : A.attr("name");page.trendDescriptions[E] = [B, D]
        }
    })
}
```

I've fixed many other problems I was getting but these are the ones I just can't understand how to fix. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use jQuery before it's loaded.

You should place that code inside your ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // place code here
});
```

Although to be really Drupal-friendly, you should use [Drupal's behaviors](http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/drupal-behaviors-quick-how).

Comment: I added this at the beginning of the file. I'm not getting the second error but the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined:' stays.
    (function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
        Drupal.behaviors.stocksTicker = {
            attach: function( context, settings ) {
                page.trendDescriptions = {};
                loadTrendDescriptions();
            }
        }
    })(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);

Comment: Could that be because this code is using jQuery to load jQuery? Or am I misunderstanding?